# Maven Javadoc plugin - can't create custom doclet

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-plugin

I am trying to use Maven's Javadoc plugin in order to generate an XML file, but it doesn't seem to generate it. My code:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <doclet>BADoclet</doclet>
        <outputDirectory>C:\work\</outputDirectory>
        <additionalparam>-b4atarget "C:\work\[project_name]-[version].xml"</additionalparam>
        <show>private</show>
        <sourceFileIncludes>
            <sourceFileInclude>com.[company_name].android.publish.b4a.*</sourceFileInclude>
        </sourceFileIncludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I'm running the plugin by calling the goal **javadoc:javadoc**

Build is successful, but no javadoc xml file is generated.

ETA: I am doing this because i'm trying to create a wrapper from Java (Android) to B4A, and B4A needs an XML. I used to do it manually in Eclipse by choosing "Project -> Create Javadoc", and in the 'Extra Javadoc options" I would put "-b4atarget "C:...\B4AWrapper.xml". That would create the desired XML in the directory I specified.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You should see this, as an [example](https://github.com/eaaltonen/lombok-maven-multimodule). It's a github project, where you can generate javadoc with maven.

Comment: @NagyVilmos it is very similar to my code. Still doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Is it in the `reporting` tag? Could you provide a MVCE to github?

Comment: @NagyVilmos nope, it is under <build>. I cannot provide a MVCE..

Comment: Can you give me a hint why you want to create an xml via maven-javadoc-plugin ? Where is documented that you can create an xml file ?

Comment: @khmarbaise It isn't documented that it is possible, but i'm trying to create a wrapper from Java (Android) to B4A, and B4A needs an XML. I used to do it manually in Eclipse by choosing "Project -> Create Javadoc", and in the 'Extra Javadoc options" I would put "-b4atarget "C:\...\B4AWrapper.xml". That would create the desired XML in the directory I specified.

Comment: If it is not documented than it is not possible. Furthermore i would suggest to take a look at the [maven-android-plugin](http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/) if it supports the things you need.

Comment: @khmarbaise there is a documentation for 'Using Alternate Doclet', which is what i'm trying to do. But i'm trying to add an additional option which generates an XML file, which is not documented. I'm pretty sure it's doable because I do it manually by adding another parameter in 'Extra Javadoc options'.

Comment: Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699957/maven-javadoc-plugin-javadoc-bundle-options

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking the output directory is a path relative to the root directory of the build.  I suspect you're creating an invalid file name by specifying an absolute path.

try `<outputDirectory>a/b</outputDirectory>` and look in target/a/b in your project for your output

Comment: The folder a/b wasn't created. And anyway, the whole purpose is for the XML file to be created outside of the target directory. Is it not possible ?