# Maven Javadoc Plugin javadoc-bundle-options

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

I have defined the plugin in my pom.xml as following:

```
<plugin>
                       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                       <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                       <version>2.10.3</version>
                       <configuration>
                             <doclet>BADoclet</doclet>
                             <docletPath>${basedir}</docletPath>
                             <additionalparam>-b4atarget B4AWrapper_${inAppVersion}.xml</additionalparam>
                             <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                             <outputDirectory>${basedir}</outputDirectory>
                             <detectOfflineLinks>false</detectOfflineLinks>
                       </configuration>
                       <executions>
                             <execution>
                                    <goals>
                                           <goal>javadoc</goal>
                                           <goal>test-javadoc</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <phase>site</phase>
                                    <configuration>
                                           <!-- Specific configuration for the given reports ... -->
                                    </configuration>
                             </execution>
                       </executions>
                </plugin>
```

When running javadoc:javadoc goal i get the following error:

> Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\jre..\bin\javadoc.exe"
>   @options @packages
>
> Refer to the generated Javadoc files in
>   'C:\work\workspace\B4AWrapper\target\site\apidocs' dir.
>
> ```
>    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.executeJavadocCommandLine(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:5163)
>    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.executeReport(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:2075)
>    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.JavadocReport.generate(JavadocReport.java:130)
>    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.JavadocReport.execute(JavadocReport.java:318)
>    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
>    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
>    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
>    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
>    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
>    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
>    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
>    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
>    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
>    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
> ```

After execution, i see that

> javadoc-bundle-options

directory is created under target directory

and also that the options file (site/apidocs/options) contains the following:

> -linkoffline 'http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api' 'C:/work/workspace/B4AWrapper/target/javadoc-bundle-options'

I need to somehow remove the C:/work/workspace/B4AWrapper/target/javadoc-bundle-options to make everything work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:
Add the following to plugin decleration:

```
<useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
```